# pub serve Transformer library "package:observe/transformer.dart" not found

Tags: dart, dart-pub

When run pub serve on Mac, it could not find transformer.dart:

```
Transformer library "package:observe/transformer.dart" not found
```

I'm using OSX 10.9, DartEditor 30798.
pub build works fine.
I searched and saw pub build fails if proxy is define. But I'm connecting to network directory without proxy.

Here is the observe package under packages directory, transformer.dart is there:

```
observe
├── html.dart
├── observe.dart
├── src
│   ├── bind_property.dart
│   ├── change_notifier.dart
│   ├── change_record.dart
│   ├── compound_path_observer.dart
│   ├── dirty_check.dart
│   ├── list_diff.dart
│   ├── list_path_observer.dart
│   ├── metadata.dart
│   ├── microtask.dart
│   ├── observable.dart
│   ├── observable_box.dart
│   ├── observable_list.dart
│   ├── observable_map.dart
│   ├── path_observer.dart
│   └── to_observable.dart
├── transform.dart
└── transformer.dart
```

Answer (score 1):

I had such problem in the renamed polymer project. After I made new polymer project and copy all logic in created files. The problem was solved.